# react-hook-form controller with materialUI TextField form results in a TypeError: e.target is undefined when using onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, onchange, react-hook-form

I've come across something interesting and would like to ask for some help.

I keep getting an error `TypeError: e.target is undefined` when trying to do an `onChange`.

I have a setup similar to this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function LogInForm() {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("asdf");

    const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

    const updateUserName = (e) => {
    setUserName(e.target.value);
    };

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    };

    return (
    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs>
            <Controller
            as={<TextField />}
            name="user_name"
            label="Username"
            control={control}
            value={userName}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="user_name"
            autoComplete="Username"
            autoFocus
            // onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
            // onChange={([e]) => setUserName(e.value)}
            onChange={updateUserName}
            />
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
        </form>
    )
}
```

You'll notice a couple of commented out attempts on the onChange.  ALL three of these come up with the same error `TypeError: e.target is undefined`.

Now I can only assume this is due to the `react-hook-form` using the `Controller` to wrap the `TextField`?

How can I still do an onChange, to change the state in this example?  I've spent some hours on this but have come to a wall and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**  In response to a test request I added:

```
const updateUserName = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setUserName(e.target.value);
    console.log(e);
};
```

This resulted in an empty array in the console.

Comment: Could you print what is the result of the onChange event?  In the updateUserName function print the parameter "e"

Comment: @YoandryCollazo  I have done this now and updated the main question.  Thank you

Comment: @robster Can you please try this! `onChange={{([ event ]) => updateUserName(event)}}`

Comment: @DeepakSingh in the end it turned out `onChange={([event]) => setUserName(event.target.value)}` did what was needed. Thank you so much for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud you check this [React-Form-Hook Controller Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller)

```
   onChange={{([ event ]) => event.target.value}}
onChange={{([ { checked } ]) => ({ checked })}}
```

Check this example using onChange
[Example using onChange](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/examples/validationOnFieldChange.tsx)

Comment: Thank you, this worked as expected.  onChange={([event]) => setUserName(event.target.value)}  So simple in the end

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try it like this!

```
<Controller
  as={<TextField />}
  name="user_name"
  label="Username"
  control={control}
  value={userName}
  variant="outlined"
  margin="normal"
  required
  fullWidth
  id="user_name"
  autoComplete="Username"
  autoFocus
  onChange={([ event ]) => {
    updateUserName(event)
    return event.target.value
  }}
/>
```

And then your `updateUserName` will listen to the changes as you have already written.

```
const updateUserName = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  setUserName(e.target.value);
};
```

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your answer.  This worked partially and has confused me even more now.  So definitely now the console.log(e.target.value) is showing realtime in the console as I type.  So that's working just fine.  

However, on my submit code as shown in the original question 

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        };

 The log show "user_name: undefined" yet my other fields (not shown above) do show data.  I'm really stumped here.  It's as if the value={userName} is not working or the setUserName(e.target.value) is not working maybe?

Comment: @robster I updated the answer, try that. Good luck!!